# Scrapy run for loop within nested json objects

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am scraping a json api using scrapy and want to loop through the offers and then the outcomes as shown in the screenshot below. I am getting to the offers OK but then not sure what to write for the get() as its unlabeled. Everything I have tried leads to an error of 'list' object has no attribute get.

[image]

My code is below:

```
import scrapy
import json

class DkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dk'
    allowed_domains = ['sportsbook.draftkings.com']
    start_urls = ['https://sportsbook.draftkings.com//sites/US-SB/api/v4/eventgroups/88670846/categories/583/subcategories/4991']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = json.loads(response.body)
        cats = items.get('eventGroup').get('offerCategories')

        for cat in cats:
            groups = str(cat.get('name'))

            if groups == "Player Props":
                subcats = cat.get('offerSubcategoryDescriptors')

                for subcat in subcats:
                    markets = str(subcat.get('name'))

                    if markets == "Points":
                        games = subcat.get('offerSubcategory').get('offers')

                        for game in games:
                            outcomes = game.get('outcomes')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was only one blank entry than you need to write `for game in games[0]:`, but since you have multiple blank keys then you need to loop through them to get all the info you want.

Solution with your approach:

```py
import scrapy


class DkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dk'
    allowed_domains = ['sportsbook.draftkings.com']
    start_urls = ['https://sportsbook.draftkings.com//sites/US-SB/api/v4/eventgroups/88670846/categories/583/subcategories/4991']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = response.json()
        cats = items.get('eventGroup').get('offerCategories')

        for cat in cats:
            groups = str(cat.get('name'))

            if groups == "Player Props":
                subcats = cat.get('offerSubcategoryDescriptors')

                for subcat in subcats:
                    markets = str(subcat.get('name'))

                    if markets == "Points":
                        games = subcat.get('offerSubcategory').get('offers')

                        for game in games:
                            for in_game in game:
                                outcomes = in_game.get('outcomes')
                                for outcome in outcomes:
                                    print(outcome['participant'])
```

But notice that you're doing more iterations than you actually need so the runtime will be longer. Either put a break or just do something like this:

```py
import scrapy
import json


class DkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dk'
    allowed_domains = ['sportsbook.draftkings.com']
    start_urls = ['https://sportsbook.draftkings.com//sites/US-SB/api/v4/eventgroups/88670846/categories/583/subcategories/4991']

    def parse(self, response):
        # from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
        # inspect_response(response, self)
        games = json.loads(response.body)['eventGroup']['offerCategories'][1]['offerSubcategoryDescriptors'][1]['offerSubcategory']['offers']
        for game in games:
            for in_game in game:
                outcomes = in_game.get('outcomes')
                for outcome in outcomes:
                    # Get whatever info you want here
                    print(outcome['participant'])
```